# AWS secrets manager: how to decrypt data when secret has been rotated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

This question is about the rotation of AWS secrets manager. When creating a secret, you could choose rotation frequency, but I can't figure out how rotation works.

Imagine a scenario like the following.

1. You create a secret `A1` in aws secret manager, and specify the rotation frequency is 30 days.
2. You encrypt the data with `A1`.
3. 30 days later, `A1` has been rotated to be `A2`.
4. then, you program retrieves AWS secret manager and got the value of `A2`. How do you decrypt the data that has been encrypted with `A1`?

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly are you storing an encryption key in your Secrets Manager?

Comment: I use secret manager to store access_token, app_secret, most of them don't need to be rotated. I am curious about the usage of aws secret manager rotation. In which case, it will be used?

Comment: I have attached an answer explaining the use cases, as well as expanding on encryption in AWS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secrets Manager rotation is primarily used for API keys or passwords.

Your encrypted values are stored in the Secrets Manager secret, but the encryption key itself is stored in KMS.

When the rotation occurs, these values are replaced by the same KMS customer master key will be used to encrypt the new value.

If you're ever wanting to store an encryption key you would use either [AWS KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/), or [AWS CloudHSM](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/) (if your organisation has specific regulatory requirements or wants to invest in a dedicated HSM).

Answer (score 1):

You should use KMS for storing encryption keys, not Secrets Manager. You can rotate encryption keys in KMS while keeping the old keys available.

Secrets Manager is for things like passwords, where rotation involves updating an account to have a new password, and the old password would be no longer needed.